# Bones messes up my model?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

I just made a 3D model of a humanoid Darkrai from Pokémon, just for fun, and I wanted to make a little animation with it.

So what I did was;

I made the half of the model and applied the mirror modifier to create the other half.
Everything went well, untill I added the bones to it + with automatic weights.
It just completely messed up the model and I'm quite sad about it.

I'm only a student so I don't know all tricks.
I hope someone can help me!!

[image]
[image]

Comment: generally the basic mesh pose is a T pose, meaning the arms should be in horizontal position, it will help to have a better Automatic Weight parentage, and also give a better result when you rise the arm bones

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This helped me alot!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that the weights are automatic.... They mess up the model!

I found a good tutorial about rigging and animating in Blender and at the 11 minute he starts to show how to weight paint correctly.

Link of the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mhQY2_gVoVg

I hope that helps!

Bye!

Comment: This helped alot! Thank you, but some problems still remain. When I bend the arms, they shrink or get flat... I think I might just import free rigged arms and conect it to my model, thank you anyway!!

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer. While the video may be useful, it is better to include an explanation about the solution in the answer text. Otherwise if the link goes down your answer becomes empty and useless

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Okay, that's a point. Thank you!